# Ubuntu 22.04 when the computer start, it says: Clearing orphan files!

Tags: boot

When my computer go in sleep mode, the screen goes black and it doesn't restart when i move my mouse. I must restart by pushing the start button. Then, when it start, it says: "clearing orphan files". I must have done something wrong.
Any ideas of what it is?

Comment: Everything you described seems like the normal consequence of a crash that occurred during sleep or wakeup.

Comment: OK. Thanks! I will investigate that!

Comment: I ran Bleachbit in the terminal and it seems to have worked!